# get data from input to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, each

```
<h2><a href="#" id="addScnt">Add Another Input Box</a></h2>

<div id="p_scents">
    <p>
        <label for="p_scnts"><input type="text" id="p_scnt" size="20" name="p_scnt" value="" placeholder="Input Value" /> <input type="checkbox" id="c_scnt" name="c_scnt" class="show"> <input type="text" id="more" name="more" class="hide"> </label>
    </p>
</div>

<span id="getall">Get all</span>
```

ALL CODE: http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/1420/

Is possible click on Get all and get all data from all inputs and next use them with loop each and get data: **this.one** (first input(text)), **this.two** (second input(checkbox)), **this.three** (third input - hidden )? for example:

```
$("#getall").click(function(){

        //here get all data to array, but how?

        array.each(function(i){
           var html = $("<tr><td>this.one</td><td>this.two</td><td>this.three</td></tr>").appendTo("#myTable");
        });

    })
```

**LIVE:**  http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/1420/

Comment: You need to remove the `id` attribute from the elements you are cloning. With the code you have now, you're getting repeated ids everywhere, which is not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work?

```
$("#getall").click(function(){
      var myRow = document.createElement("tr");

      var array = new Array()
      $.each($("#p_scents").find("p"), function(ind, elem) {
          var inputCol = new Array();
          console.log("Adding row");
          $.each($(elem).find("input"), function(ind2, inputElem) {
              if ($(inputElem).attr("type") != "checkbox") {
                 inputCol [inputCol .length] = $(inputElem).val();                  
              }
              else {
                  inputCol [inputCol .length] = $(inputElem).is(":checked");
              }
          });
          array[array.length] = inputCol;
      });
        console.log("Outputting results");
        for (var i in array) {
            console.log("Row: "+i);
            for (var j in array[i]) {
               console.log("Input: "+j + " == " + array[i][j]);         
            }                    
        }

    });
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/1425/ please add new row and fill in.  i have error: elem.val is not a function
 

array[array.length] = elem.val();

Comment: Edited my answer appropriately - using a class on your inputs to make sure I only get the inputs you are actually after - see http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/1434/ for full working jsFiddle

Comment: thanks, but in this example i dont know where input values are related. for example in first line input can be only two values, and in second line can be three values. i would like have each line in seperately variables, for example for each: this.one, this.two, this.three

Comment: all data from first line (input, checkbox, input) should be one subarray, all data from second line (input, checkbox, input) should be one subarray etc. now all data are in array - i dont know relation between this. now is array = {first, true, first, second, false}. i would like array = {array[0] = {first, true, first}, array[1] = {second, false}}

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = new Array();

$( 'input' ).each(function(index)
{
    arr[arr.length] = $(this).val();
})
```